# Most efficient way of checking for a return from a function call in Perl

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference

I want to add the return value from the function call to an array iff something is returned (not by default, i.e. if I have a `return` statement in the subroutine.)

so I'm using `unshift @{$errors}, "HashValidator::$vfunction($hashref)";` but this actually adds the string of the function call to the array. I also tried `unshift @{$errors}, $temp if defined my $temp = "HashValidator::$vfunction($hashref)";` with the same result. What would a perl one-liner look like that does this efficiently (I know I can do the ugly, multi-line check but I want to learn).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using eval:

```
push @{$errors}, eval "HashValidator::$vfunction($hashref)"
```

The following works for me with perl 5.12, and checks for undef return values:

```
my $foo = "foo";
my $val = eval "Foo::$foo()"
push @arry,$val if ($val);
```

Comment: Tried that. get a 'bad name after :: at $line' error. Re:eval - eval returns undef in scalar context and empty list in list context. Tried that as well. :(

Comment: Yup, that works :D , but it doesn't check for undef values being returned. So most of my array is uninitialized values when I print. How would you go about the second part?

Comment: Aha, isn't that solution not too good in terms of performance? I thought of that, and then realized that the interpreter would have no way of knowing that `Foo::$foo()` call should be cached - so doesn't this double the run time?

Comment: if you are worried about performance then simply break it up into 2 lines storing the result of the eval in a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

> iff something is returned (not by
>   default, i.e. if I have a return
>   statement in the subroutine.)

There could be a gotcha here. Perl *always* returns something, even if you don't mean to:

```
my $failures = 0;
sub word_to_number {
    my $_ = shift;
    /one/ and return 1;
    /two/ and return 2;
    ++$failures; # whoops, equivalent to return ++$failures
}
```

The last expression in a sub is used as the return value if there is no explicit return. To return "nothing", use bare return, which returns `undef` or the empty list, depending on context:

```
my $failures = 0;
sub word_to_number {
    my $_ = shift;
    /one/ and return 1;
    /two/ and return 2;
    ++$failures;
    return;
}
```

This behaviour is actually useful for things like sorting:

```
my @results = sort { $a->name cmp $b->name } @list;
```

where we have passed in the anonymous subroutine:

```
{
    $a->name cmp $b->name # equivalent to return $a->name cmp $b->name
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is **no need** to use the string form of `eval` (or any form for that matter).  Not only is it slow, but it also can silently trap errors and could lead to untrusted code execution if used with a tainted input.  To write a virtual function call in Perl, you can either work with the symbol table directly, or use a symbolic reference:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;

{package HashValidator;
    sub test_ok   {exists $_[0]{ok}}
    sub test_fail {exists $_[0]{fail}}
}


my $hashref = {ok => 1};
my $errors;

for my $vFunction qw(test_ok test_fail) {

    # to call the function:
    say "glob deref: $vFunction: ", $HashValidator::{$vFunction}->($hashref);
    {no strict 'refs';
    say "symbolic:   $vFunction: ", &{"HashValidator::$vFunction"}($hashref)}

    # to conditionally use the result (if it is a true boolean value):
    if (my $ret = $HashValidator::{$vFunction}->($hashref)) {
        push @$errors, $ret;
    }

    # or to keep the function call in list context:
    push @$errors, grep $_, $HashValidator::{$vFunction}->($hashref);

    # or to golf it:
    push @$errors, $HashValidator::{$vFunction}->($hashref) || ();
}

say @$errors.': ', join ', ' => @$errors;
```

which prints:

```
glob deref: test_ok: 1
symbolic:   test_ok: 1
glob deref: test_fail: 
symbolic:   test_fail: 
3: 1, 1, 1
```

If you are working with object oriented code, virtual method calls are even easier, with no symbol table or symbolic references:

```
$obj->$vMethod(...)
```